# mysql UPDATE WHERE x<(SELECT WHERE)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I want update like this, but there is a problem with it:

```
UPDATE table
SET data=1
WHERE data2 < (
    SELECT MIN(data2)
    FROM table
    WHERE data2 < int
    AND data=0
)
```

Error: You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause

How it works?

I want set data to 1 in table where data2(timestamp) in same table is lower than actual timestamp, and it is the lowest and in that row data is 0

Thanks

Comment: So what (exact) error are you seeing?

Comment: there are problems with ur question: :)

Comment: It's a good idea to say exactly what you *want to do*, instead of having people guess from code which you have already said is incorrect.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't `SELECT` from the same table you're trying to `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tough to tell from your example but if data and data2 are consistent, why not do:

```
UPDATE table SET data=1 WHERE data2 < int AND data = 0
```

Comment: I want set data to 1 in table where data2(timestamp) in same table is lower than actual timestamp, and it is the lowest and in that row data is 0